# How to POST from Angular to Slim?

Tags: php, angularjs, post, routes, slim

I have the following code, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried to search for a solution, but most of them are older and very specific answers.

I get up to this point:

1. The template loads in ng-view via the config.
2. The form submits on click.
3. Nothing happens.

I check the POST with the Google Console in Network, and it doesn't fire.

What am I missing? I got most of the code from [this article](http://www.blog.iamaronbarbosa.com/building-a-basic-crud-application-using-angularjs-and-slim-php-framework-part-1/).

**HTML View** i.e. the form

```
<h2>Add new job</h2>
<form novalidate name="AddNewForm" method="post" action="">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="job.title" placeholder="Title" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="job.company" placeholder="Company" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="job.description" placeholder="Description" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="job.location" placeholder="Location" required />
    <br/>
    <button ng-disabled="AddNewForm.$invalid || isUnchanged(job)" ng-click="add_new(job)" class="btn">Save!</button>

</form>
```

**Angular Config Controller**

```
(function() {

    angular
    .module('app')
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/add-job', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/add-job.html',
            controller: AddController   
        });
    });

    function AddController($http, $location) {
        var that = this;

        that.master = {};
        that.activePath = null;

        that.add_new = function(job, AddNewForm) {
            $http.post('api/add_job', job).success(function () {
                alert("added!");
                that.reset();
                that.activePath = $location.path('/');
            });

            that.reset = function () {
                that.job = angular.copy(that.master);
            };

            that.reset();
        };
    }
})();
```

**Slim API**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App; 

$app->post('/add_job', 'addJob');

$app->run();

function addJob() {
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $job = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO jobs (title, company, description, location) VALUES (:title, :company, :description, :location)";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->bindParam("title", $job->title);
        $stmt->bindParam("company", $job->company);
        $stmt->bindParam("description", $job->description);
        $stmt->bindParam("location", $job->location);
        $stmt->execute();
        $job->id = $db->lastInsertId();
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($job); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `controllerAs` syntax in controller but `$scope` syntax in view.
Note that the article you link to uses `$scope` in controller for all variables which would match your current view setup

You need to pick one or the other so view is compatible with controller

Comment: Thanks for replying, however I am not sure I follow. :( I am purposefully avoiding `$scope` as per [John Papa's Guidelines](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide). Care to explain how can i bind the controller in the view?

Comment: well if you avoid it you need to make the view compatible by first declaring `controllerAs` alias and using that alias to prefix all controller model variables in view

Comment: For example if alias is set to `"vm"` you need `ng-click="vm.doSomething()"`

Comment: Hey man, thanks for taking the time to help me out. Adding the alias from controllerAs in front of everything solved the problem.